# Which takes precedence, Gradle build types or flavors?

Tags: android, gradle

Say I have a constant defined at both levels: in the build type I set it to "mybuild" and in the flavor I set it to "myflavor".

Such as in here:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        resValue "string", "analytics_key", "XXX_SANDBOX_KEY_XXX"
    }
}

productFlavors {
    appA {
        resValue "string", "analytics_key", "XXX_KEY_FOR_A_XXX"
    }
    appB {
        resValue "string", "analytics_key", "XXX_KEY_FOR_A_XXX"
    }
}
```

I want to send the events of the different apps (thta is, flavors) to different accounts in my analytics platform. But, if I'm debugging, I want to send them all to my sandbox account.

The original question is: which takes precedence? From my test, I can already answer that: the one in the build type.

However, the more interesting one is: is this guaranteed?

(Or, is there a better way to do this?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> is this guaranteed?

Build types generally are considered higher priority than are product flavors for things at the same level (e.g., the same module). Quoting [the documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-Flavor-Configuration):

> Usually, the Build Type configuration is an overlay over the other configuration. For instance, the Build Type's packageNameSuffix is appended to the Product Flavor's packageName.

Manifest merging, though, is rather complicated, requiring [its own set of docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger).

In your case, you are creating resources. In that case, it should follow the same rules as if you had put these values as string resources in relevant sourcesets:

> All resources (Android res and assets) are used using overlay priority where the Build Type overrides the Product Flavor, which overrides the main sourceSet.

If `resValue` started behaving differently than the equivalent using sourcesets, I would consider that to be a bug.

Comment: @espinchi: "not if I use XML resources, or if I mix them (as I intended)" -- I definitely would not use both `resValue` and "real" resources for the same resource type and name, as I rather doubt that is an expected use pattern. However, if anything, using resource files alone should be safer, as that behavior is explicitly documented. What is your scenario where that is not working?

Comment: (Sorry, I deleted my previous comment by mistake.) Yes, using only resources works as intended, and the end result is actually more readable. Initially, I wanted to make the overriding a bit more explicit in the build.gradle file, but I see it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you could place your resources in a string.xml file in the source-folder of your buildType-folder, productFlavour-folder or in the buildVariant-folder.

If you place it in the buildVariant-folder, if think it will be guaranteed that this value will be used.

```
src-Root
    |->main
    |->debugAppA <- resources in this combination will be given precedence.
    |   |->res
    |      |->values
    |         |-> strings.xml
    |-> debug
    |   |->res
    |      |->values
    |         |-> strings.xml
    |-> appA
    |   |->res
    |      |->values
    |         |-> strings.xml
```

Comment: +1. Yes, it is confirmed (by CommonsWare's references) that your proposal would indeed work. In the end, I'll do a hybrid: string.xml for the flavors, and build.gradle for the build type that overrides them.

Comment: @espinchi , how it is possible ? can you check my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33014820/gradle-exclude-file-creating-jar-in-a-subproject