# Gradle : Exclude file creating jar in a subproject

Tags: java, ant, gradle, migration

I have a multi-module-project. The structure is as follows.

```
root-project
------------
├── project-A
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── resources
│               └── myFile.xml
├── project-B
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── resources
│               └── myFile.xml
└── project-shared
    └── src
        └── main
            └── resources
                └── myFile.xml
```

(':project-A') is depends on (':project-shared') and (':project-B')
*My issue is when I build (':project-A')*

I have a filtertocken (to replace version number) in myFile.xml. So I need myFile.xml under project-A to be in project-A.jar file. But unfortunately project-A.jar contains myFile.xml from project-shared. I tried removing myFile.xml from project-shared and then while building project-A , the project-A jar contains myFile.xml from project-B.

I need myFile.xml file in project-A.jar whenever I build it.
Is there any way ?

code is as follows:

```
processResources() {
    java.lang.String version        = project.version
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: ['VERSION': version])
}

dependencies { 
compile project(':project-shared')
compile project(':project-B')
...
...
}

//Tried different ideas..
tasks['compileJava'].dependsOn      += [processResources]
tasks['installHost'].dependsOn      += [processResources]
tasks['jar'].dependsOn              += [processResources]
```

Is there any way **to exclude the following files while building project-A ?**
1. project-B/src/main/resources/myFile.xml
2. project-shared/src/main/resources/myFile.xml
**Or Only keep project-A/src/main/resources/myFile.xml always in project-A.jar**

Comment: To be clear, you want the whole XML file to be replaced, right? (In Android, we usually want them merged.) I would try moving `myFile.xml` in `project-A` to a flavor or a build type, since those will end up taking precedence.

Comment: Why don't you delete this file from `project-B` and `project-shared`?

Comment: @espinchi , Thank you.. I will try copying on to the file to merge. That will work. @ opal , users may build whole project (root-project) in once or may be each project one by one. myFile.xml is different for each project.